# How to query several documents by using specific headers in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, import, match, transpose, google-query-language

I have several workbooks, each consisting of form results from various surveys and questionnaires I've conducted over time. What I would like to accomplish is import only specific columns by matching their headers from all of these documents. For example, I would like to collect the emails of all English speaking respondents who opted for the newsletter.
Here are the examples I would like to unify into a single sheet:

- Workbook 1 > Sheet X > Column B (Email), Column E (Language), Column X (Newsletter)
- Workbook 1 > Sheet Y > Column B (Email), Column C (Language), Column G (Newsletter)
- Workbook 2 > Sheet Z > Column A (Email), Column C (Language), Column J (Newsletter)
- etc.

The result should be something like Workbook 3 > Sheet X >

`query({Workbook 1(Sheet!Range); Workbook 2(Sheet!Range)},"SELECT Email WHERE Language='English' AND Newsletter='Yes'"`

from indicated workbooks and sheets.

I've figured how to import data from external sheets using

`=query(importrange(URL, Sheet!Range), Query)`

and managed to match headers using the following trick:

`=QUERY(data!A:X,"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Email addres",data!A1:X1,0),4),1,""))`, but only within the same workbook.

I tried combining these but ran into various errors. How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this example for 3 spreadsheets where row 1 contains headers and each spreadsheet contains all 3 columns:

```
=INDEX(QYERY({
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("id1", "sheetname!A1:Z"))), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Email|Language|Newsletter'", 0));
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("id2", "sheetname!A1:Z"))), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Email|Language|Newsletter'", 0));
 TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("id3", "sheetname!A1:Z"))), 
 "where Col1 matches 'Email|Language|Newsletter'", 0))}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

Comment: Although it fetches unwanted values as well, it works like a charm! I added an extra sheet that uses this formula to import the three columns I need from all the documents and used a simple query to filter the values in the actual sheet _(e.g., Language=""English"" and Newsletter=""Yes"")._